# Downloading API of a web page

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

Trying to download the API file that governs connection between the web site and database. How to do it?

Already tried Httrack, wget and open explorer but they all only download the web site. Of course the entire web site but the thing "API" I am not able to find.

To be more specific on the topic:
Suppose a database containing different accounts and those accounts contain age of the account holder. The web site when log in with the credentials shows the age of that particular user.

Now whenever I am trying to download the web what I am getting is the web site layout with that fix number that is one part (Done) and other is to get the file which is responsible for that number change in the web.

The file which makes the connection.
For any further clarification please ask.

Comment: You can access the front-end HTML contents, and the links which do the get or post calls. But you cannot get the database access. The thing responsible for changing values according to the use are Queries to the database which are executed by the APIs. You get the APIs and parameters, but not the Queries. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes how can i get that APIs?

Answer (score 0):

In any popular browser:

- In your request page, right click. Select "Inspect Element".
- Click "Network" menu.
- (Optionally) Clear all the logs.
- In the front-end, enter Credentials and login.

You will have all the details in there. Check for Method - POST links, click on it and explore the details.

Comment: but how to download every APIs linked to that http

Comment: Elaborate please.